# ListBlobs does not list UnCommitted blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I tried use blobstate to list uncommitted blobs. But GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync with BlobStates.Uncommitted return same result as with BlobStates.None.

My code

```
Console.WriteLine("BlobStates " + blobStates);

        await foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobHierarchyItem in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(
            BlobTraits.None, blobStates))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blob.Name " + blobHierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Blob.Properties.LastModified " + blobHierarchyItem.Blob.Properties.LastModified);
        }
```

Result

BlobStates Uncommitted

Blob.Name testing_6.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:04 +00:00

Blob.Name testing_7.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:25 +00:00

Blob.Name testing_8.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 13:47:46 +00:00

BlobStates None

Blob.Name testing_6.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:04 +00:00

Blob.Name testing_7.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:25 +00:00

Blob.Name testing_8.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 13:47:46 +00:00

Do I something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can list blobs in a flat listing structure, or hierarchically

Hierarchical listing returns blobs as though they were organized into folders

To **list blob versions or snapshots, specify the BlobStates parameter** with the Version or Snapshot field. Versions and snapshots are listed from oldest to newest

Reference Links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list#list-blob-versions-or-snapshots

Comment: Hi @SureshBabu-MT, 

thanks for answer but I want to list blobs according BlobState Uncommitted, not according BlobState Verizon or Snapshot. 

With Regards 
Radek